# IOS MDM Device Tracking is it possible?

Tags: ios, mdm

Hi could any one please answer to my questions. 
1)Can we do device tracking using IOS MDM?
2)Many of forums are showing that an application which has device tracking functionality,Apple  rejects the application.

Any answer would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Store Guidelines:

> 17.1 Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to
>   information about how and where the data will be used
>
> 4.1 Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected
>
> 4.2 Apps that use location-based APIs for automatic or autonomous control of vehicles, aircraft, or other devices will be rejected
>
> 4.3 Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected
>
> 4.4 Location data can only be used when directly relevant to the features and services provided by the App to the user or to support
>   approved advertising uses

There may be more that affect you: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: Hi unicorn. Thank you Unicorn .Could you please tell me that these constarints are applicable for Enterprise license also?

Comment: If you are not submitting them to the App Store, only distributing in-house, then these constraints to not apply. They only apply to apples App Store.